# Connect C-lightning to a remote bitcoind through tor

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, lightning-network, core-lightning, tor

I would like to connect my C-lightning node to a remote Bitcoin node, in order to be able to run `lightningd` on a small storage capacity VPS.

I could achieve this by using clearnet connection and wanted to know if would be possible to proxy the connection through the Tor network ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes but not by default.

C-lightning uses a [pluggable Bitcoin backend](https://lightning.readthedocs.io/PLUGINS.html#bitcoin-backend). The default one, `bcli`, will use the `bitcoin-cli` executable to make requests to a `bitcoind`.
It exposes [`bitcoin-cli`'s `rpcconnect` startup option to `lightningd`](https://lightning.readthedocs.io/lightningd-config.5.html#general-options) which does not not support onion hosts. And you probably don't want it to as *it is not meant to be exposed*.

If you want to run C-lightning without having the full block chain locally you'd probably opt for a light backend solution, such as:

- [A pruned `bitcoind`](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/#pruning) (beware of misconfiguration)
- An explorer-backed backend.
  For example, [the Sauron plugin](https://github.com/lightningd/plugins/tree/master/sauron) which you could connect to an external
  Esplora instance you would run on a machine with more space. It supports onion services.

If you really want to remotely access `bitcoind`'s RPC, you should probably opt for an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Thank you. I will check the prune parameter for bitcoind and also a plugin [c-lightning-pruning-plugin](https://github.com/Start9Labs/c-lightning-pruning-plugin)